# RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView - scroll wont work

Tags: android

I have tried many solutions found in StackOverflow now and it is not working on what I was expecting. I want to disable the Recycler View Scroll allowing only the Nested scrollView to scroll my content.

**Below is my XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/clProfileInfoContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/background_divider"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/ps_container_padding_start"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/ps_container_padding_top"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/ps_container_padding_end"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ps_container_padding_bottom"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivPhotoSelector"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/ps_photo_selector_max_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/ps_photo_selector_max_height"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_photo_selector"
                    android:maxWidth="@dimen/ps_photo_selector_max_width"
                    android:maxHeight="@dimen/ps_photo_selector_max_height"
                    android:src="@drawable/blue_profile_img_placeholder"
                    app:civ_circle_background_color="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:id="@+id/llUsernameContainer"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/ps_username_margin_start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ps_username_margin_top"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivPhotoSelector"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="Username"
                        android:textColor="@color/tvMainTextColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/ps_username_text_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivPhotoSelector"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivPhotoSelector" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btnEditProfile"
                        style="@style/AppTheme.Button.Blue"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/small_button_height"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>


                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:id="@+id/llLocationContainer"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/ps_location_margin_start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ps_location_margin_top"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivPhotoSelector"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llUsernameContainer" >

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Location"
                        android:textColor="@color/tvSubTextColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/ps_location_text_size"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/btnShare"
                        style="@style/AppTheme.Button.Blue"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/small_button_height"
                        android:minWidth="@dimen/small_share_button_min_width"
                        android:text="@string/ps_label_share_profile"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>


                <me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar.MaterialRatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/rbRating"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialRatingBar.RatingBar.Indicator"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/ps_star_rating_margin_start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ps_star_rating_margin_top"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/ps_star_rating_margin_end"
                    android:maxHeight="@dimen/ps_star_rating_max_height"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/ps_star_rating_min_height"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:rating="4"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivPhotoSelector"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llLocationContainer"
                    app:mrb_fillBackgroundStars="true"
                    app:mrb_progressBackgroundTint="@color/rbBackgroundColor"
                    app:mrb_progressTint="@color/rbProgressBackgroundColor" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/clListingContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/ps_container_padding_start"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/ps_container_padding_top"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/ps_container_padding_end"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/ps_container_padding_bottom"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/clProfileInfoContainer"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etShortBio"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/ps_bio_min_height"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:padding="@dimen/ps_bio_padding"
                    android:text="Short Bio About Yourself"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/labelColor"
                    android:background="@drawable/white_background"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvListing"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ps_listing_margin_top"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/ps_listing_padding_top"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etShortBio"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/row_user_listing_item">

                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

                <com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView
                    android:id="@+id/skUserListingLoading"
                    style="@style/SpinKitView.Wave"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:SpinKit_Color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rvListing" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and in my activity, I set this to disable the scroll of recycler view

```
private void setupListing() {
    // rvMenuList should not be null
    assert rvListing != null;
    // initialize Recycler View Adapter
    userListingAdapter = new UserListingAdapter(getContext());

    // initialize GridLayoutManager
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), gridSize);
    // initialize custom divider item decorator
    SpacesItemDecoration itemDecorator = new SpacesItemDecoration(10, 10, 30);
    rvListing.addItemDecoration(itemDecorator);

    ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(rvListing, false);
    // set the adapter to the recycler view
    rvListing.setAdapter(userListingAdapter);
    // set the layout manager to the recycler view
    rvListing.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
}
```

Here's how it looks like

[image]

Now I can't scroll the recycler view because of using this code `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(rvListing, false);` and also I can't scroll the whole content to view the other items of my recycler view.

Comment: I'd say just use `GridLayout` instead of `RecyclerView` in this context, with `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` Because the `NestedScrollView` will handle your scrolling events. Or, for another solution, extend a custom class of your `RecyclerView` and override `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` methods, then return false from both of them. (Use the recycler view you have extended on your layout too.)

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul nice solution but can you show me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got the solution. the `rvListing.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` actually works. the issue was the parent height i accidentally set it to `0dp` which is suppose to be `wrap_content`. that was the fix of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

this may work for you, apply layout behavior:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/conversation"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this **line:**

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(rvListing, false);
```

Use this **line:**

```
rvListing.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

after setting the adapter **like this:**

```
private void setupListing() {
    // rvMenuList should not be null
    assert rvListing != null;
    // initialize Recycler View Adapter
    userListingAdapter = new UserListingAdapter(getContext());

    // initialize GridLayoutManager
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), gridSize);
    // initialize custom divider item decorator
    SpacesItemDecoration itemDecorator = new SpacesItemDecoration(10, 10, 30);
    rvListing.addItemDecoration(itemDecorator);
 // set the adapter to the recycler view
    rvListing.setAdapter(userListingAdapter);
    // set the layout manager to the recycler view
    rvListing.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    rvListing.setHasFixedSize(true);

    rvListing.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

}
```

**use RecyclerView width**

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: @SecretCoder why are you using ` android:layout_height="0dp"` ? instead of using `0dp` use `wrap_content`

Comment: because I'm using Constraint layout as my parent view. 0dp or wrap_content still scrolling wont work

Comment: @SecretCoder oh I see where is the problem please whenever you use `ContraintLayout` never use `match_parent` property I have faced this issue and get rid of this by using relative layout with `wrap_content` property in or you can use 0dp for both height and width

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187308/discussion-between-tanveer-munir-and-secret-coder).

Answer (score -1):

Just override the GridLayoutManager as below, and invoke the method setCanScroll(false).

```
public class CustomLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {

private boolean canScroll;

public CustomLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}


/**
 * 
 * @param canScroll true--enable scroll, false--disable scroll
 */
public void setCanScroll(boolean canScroll) {
    this.canScroll = canScroll;
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
    return this.canScroll;
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollVertically() {
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

To disable scrolling of `RecyclerView`, you can do it programmatically:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Or through xml:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

But be careful when your `RecyclerView` contain many items. It will cause lag

Disable `RecyclerView` scrolling is bad practice, use `RecyclerView` with multiple item types instead!